# Kendo Grid : Removing a first row from the grid, always remove the last row

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, angular-reactive-forms, angular8, kendo-ui-angular2

While trying to remove any row (having form controls) from the grid, it always remove the last row.

Demo URL for the reference : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oitz5j-zvjoxf

**steps to reproduce :**

- Add few rows by clicking on the "Add" button.
- Try to discard the first row using "Discard" button.
- It always discards last row from the grid.

**versions used :**

```
Angular : 8
Angular CLI : 8.3.3
Node : 10.16.0
```

> Note : with Angular 5 the above functionality working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stackblitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oitz5j-tpkgvd)

Here, new row can be added at the end and on discarding a row specified row will be deleted.

I have used template driven form so that on adding new row id values will not be repeated. Refer the shared code.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Solution provided by you is working fine but i have to use only reactive forms as there are lot of complex validations on the controls and template driven form is not suitable for that. Can you please help with reactive forms to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Its a UI illusion I guess!

You should not use rowid manually, probably you should datasource option of kendo grid.

By the way, check this out

UI getting updated properly. Since you are using ROWID, it may get duplicated at some point.

```
<button (click)="addNewRow()">Add {{dataItem.rowID}}</button>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oitz5j-dbwzxh?file=app/app.component.ts

[image]

Comment: Same working fine with Angular 5, i am facing issue in Angular 8. Also, i checked the stackblitz shared by you but in that as well it is not deleting the selected row.

Comment: Have you seen the gif?

Comment: @RohitJindal It does remove the actual row but the value binded with the formcontrolName Id is taken as the first-row value in the grid. Maybe that's the confusion I guess. Closely take a look at the Add button Id.

Comment: @PandiyanCool Yes i see that, For example : I added 3 rows and enter ID as 1,2,3. Now i deleted row which is having ID 2. It was showing the correct index in Add button but data in ID is not correct.